# Finding the average of a data set using Apache Spark

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, average

I am learning how to use Apache Spark and I am trying to get the average temperature from each hour from a data set. The data set that I am trying to use is from weather information stored in a csv. I am having trouble finding how to first read in the csv file and then calculating the average temperature for each hour.

From the spark documentation I am using the example Scala line to read in a file.

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("README.md")
```

I have given the link for the data file below. I am using the file called JCMB_2014.csv as it is the latest one with all months covered.

[Weather Data](http://www.ed.ac.uk/schools-departments/geosciences/weather-station/download-weather-data)

Edit:
The code I have tried so far is:

```
class SimpleCSVHeader(header:Array[String]) extends Serializable {
  val index = header.zipWithIndex.toMap
  def apply(array:Array[String], key:String):String = array(index(key))
}

val csv = sc.textFile("JCMB_2014.csv")
val data = csv.map(line => line.split(",").map(elem => elem.trim))
val header = new SimpleCSVHeader(data.take(1)(0)) // we build our header 

val header = new SimpleCSVHeader(data.take(1)(0))
val rows = data.filter(line => header(line,"date-time") != "date-time")
val users = rows.map(row => header(row,"date-time")
val usersByHits = rows.map(row => header(row,"date-time") -> header(row,"surface temperature (C)").toInt)
```

Comment: From what i have gathered from documentation I have tried to read in the csv file and get the lines. I have added the code that i have tried to the original post

Comment: Where are you stuck? What is the specific problem you are having?

Comment: I am trying to essentially find the average temperature for each hour in the  csv file but I cant find out how to write the code for it. For example if there are 12 hours, I want to find the average temperature for each hour within the 12

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code for calculating averages on hourly basis

Step1:Read file, Filter header,extract time and temp columns

```
scala> val hourlyTemps = lines.map(line=>line.split(",")).filter(entries=>(!"time".equals(entries(3)))).map(entries=>(entries(3).toInt/60,(entries(8).toFloat,1)))
    scala> hourlyTemps.take(1)
    res25: Array[(Int, (Float, Int))] = Array((9,(10.23,1)))
```

(time/60) discards minutes and keeps only hours

Step2:Aggregate temperatures and no of occurrences

```
scala> val aggregateTemps=hourlyTemps.reduceByKey((a,b)=>(a._1+b._1,a._2+b._2))
scala> aggreateTemps.take(1)
res26: Array[(Int, (Double, Int))] = Array((34,(8565.25,620)))
```

Step2:Calculate Averages using total and no of occurrences
Find the final result below.

```
val avgTemps=aggregateTemps.map(tuple=>(tuple._1,tuple._2._1/tuple._2._2))
scala> avgTemps.collect
res28: Array[(Int, Float)] = Array((34,13.814922), (4,11.743354), (16,14.227251), (22,15.770312), (28,15.5324545), (30,15.167026), (14,13.177828), (32,14.659948), (36,12.865237), (0,11.994799), (24,15.662579), (40,12.040322), (6,11.398838), (8,11.141323), (12,12.004652), (38,12.329914), (18,15.020147), (20,15.358524), (26,15.631921), (10,11.192643), (2,11.848178), (13,12.616284), (19,15.198371), (39,12.107664), (15,13.706351), (21,15.612191), (25,15.627121), (29,15.432097), (11,11.541124), (35,13.317129), (27,15.602408), (33,14.220147), (37,12.644306), (23,15.83412), (1,11.872819), (17,14.595772), (3,11.78971), (7,11.248139), (9,11.049844), (31,14.901464), (5,11.59693))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to provide Structure definition of your CSV file and convert your RDD to DataFrame, like described [in the documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema). Dataframes provide a whole set of useful predefined statistic functions as well as the possibility to write some simple custom functions. You then will be able to compute the average with:

```
dataFrame.groupBy(<your columns here>).agg(avg(<column to compute average>)
```